# malloc and other associated functions

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I have an array named 'ArrayA' and it is full of ints but I want to add another 5 cell to the end of the array every time a condition is met. How would I do this? ( The internet is not being very helpful )

Comment: If it's a real array, you can't. If it's a `malloc`ed block of memory used as an array, `realloc` is your friend.

Comment: "The internet is not being very helpful" - well, you're on the Internet right now. You're asking for help. People are helping you. You better not say things like this one...

Comment: @user1744194 Sr. if you question as been answer please consider to accepted one of them. So other will know that this problem is already solve. See here how to accept and answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

If this is a static array, you will have to create a new one with more space and copy the data yourself. If it was allocated with malloc(), as the title to your question suggests, then you can use realloc() to do this more-or-less automatically. Note that the address of your array will, in general, have changed.

It is precisely because of the need for "dynamic" arrays that grow (and shrink) as needed, that languages like C++ introduced vectors. They do the management under the covers.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) function.

Also note that adding 5 cells is not the best performance solution.
It is best to double the size of your arrays every time an array increase is needed.
Use two variables, one for the **size** (the number of integers used) and one for **capacity** (the actual memory size of arrays)

Answer (score -1):

In a modern OS it is generally safe to assume that if you allocate **a lot** of memory that you don't use then it will not actually consume physical RAM, but only exist as virtual mappings. The OS will provide physical RAM as soon as a page (today generally in chunks of 4Kb) is used for the first time.

You can specifically enforce this behavior by using `mmap` to create a large anonymous mapping (`MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS`) e.g. as much as you intend to hold at maximum. On modern x64 systems virtual mappings can be up to 64Tb large. It is logically memory available to your program, but in practice pages will be added to it as you start using them.

`realloc` as described by the other posters is the naiive way to resize a `malloc` mapping, but make sure that realloc was successful. It can fail!

Problems with memory arise when you use memory once, don't deallocate it and stop using it. In contrast allocated, but untouched memory generally does not actually use resources other then VM table entries.